# Given sum of uniform random variables $Z_1 + Z_2 + \dots + Z_n =1$,what's the probability that $k$ R.Vs are at least $1/n$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Given sum of uniform random variables on $[0,1]$, $Z_1 + Z_2 + \dots + Z_n = 1$, what is the probability that exactly k random variables are at least $\frac{1}{n}$?

In other words, what's

$Pr[\text{exactly k random variables are at least }\frac{1}{n} \mid Z_1 + Z_2 + \ldots + Z_n = 1]$

where $Z_i$s are uniform random variables on $[0,1]$?

Thanks!

Comment: How are $Z_i$ sampled in a way that they are uniform random variables and they satisfy that sum criteria? The sum criteria makes them non uniform.

Comment: @Hugh I think it is conditional probability.

Comment: The posts means to say something like $P(\text{at least $k$ $Z_i$ are at least $1/n$}\mid Z_1+\dotsb+Z_n = 1)$

Answer (score 1):

The probability for $j$ particular variables to be at least $\frac1n$ is

$$
\left(1-\frac jn\right)^{n-1}\;,
$$

so by [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) the probability for exactly $k$ variables to be at least $\frac1n$ is

$$
\sum_{j=k}^n(-1)^{j-k}\binom nj\binom jk\left(1-\frac jn\right)^{n-1}\;.
$$

I'm not aware of any way to simplify this.