# $n$ points be placed uniformly at random on the boundary of a circle of circumference $1$.. what's the $n$ arcs' length distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $n$ points be placed uniformly at random on the boundary of a circle
of circumference $1$.

These n points divide the circle into $n$ arcs.

Let $Z_i$ for $1 \le i \le n$
be the length of these arcs in some arbitrary order, and let $X$ be the number of $Z_i$ that
are at least $\frac{1}{n}$.

What is $E[X]$ and $Var[X]$?

Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks..

(By the way this problem is exercise 8.12 from the book 'Probability and Computing' by Mitzenmacher and Upfal)

Comment: It would have made sense to link this question to [your previous, related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805573) to avoid unnecessary duplication of efforts.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

If you cut the circle along the first placed point, you can see that the situation is equivalent to taking the interval $[0,1]$ and placing $n-1$ points uniformly at random into the interval.

Comment: Thanks for giving the hint. However, I've actually arrived at that point before posting this question.. but i have no idea what to do next.. could you give me more specific hints? Thanks.

Comment: @asqdf You should have indicated that in the post. That is why you need to post all attempts and work in progress so that people don't tell you something you already know.

Answer (score 1):

This is a corollary of the answer to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805573). The probability for $j$ particular lengths to be at least $\frac1n$ is

$$
\left(1-\frac jn\right)^{n-1}\;.
$$

Thus the probability for a given length to be at least $\frac1n$ is $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n-1}$, so by linearity of expectation

$$E[X]=n\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n-1}\;.$$

The probability for two particular lengths to be at least $\frac1n$ is $\left(1-\frac2n\right)^{n-1}$, so, again by linearity of expectation,

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(X)&=E\left[X^2\right]-E[X]^2\\
&=n(n-1)\left(1-\frac2n\right)^{n-1}+n\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n-1}-n^2\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{2(n-1)}\\
&=n(n-1)\left(1-\frac2n\right)^{n-1}+n\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n-1}-n^2\left(1-\frac2n+\frac1{n^2}\right)^{n-1}\;.
\end{align}

With

\begin{align}
\left(1-x\right)^{n-1}&=\exp\left((n-1)\log(1-x)\right)\\
&=\exp\left((n-1)\left(-x-\frac{x^2}2\right)\right)\left(1+O\left(nx^3\right)\right)\;,
\end{align}

this yields

\begin{align}
E[X]&=n\exp\left((n-1)\left(-\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}\right)\right)+O\left(\frac1n\right)\\
&=\frac n{\mathrm e}+\frac1{2\mathrm e}+O\left(\frac1n\right)
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(X)&=n^2\left(\exp\left((n-1)\left(-\frac2n-\frac2{n^2}\right)\right)-\exp\left((n-1)\left(-\frac2n-\frac2{n^2}+\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)\right)
\\
&+n\left(\exp\left((n-1)\left(-\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}\right)\right)-\exp\left((n-1)\left(-\frac2n-\frac2{n^2}\right)\right)\right)+O(1)\\
&=n^2\left(\exp(-2)-\exp\left(-2+\frac1n\right)\right)+n\left(\exp(-1)-\exp(-2)\right)+O(1)\\
&=n\left(\frac1{\mathrm e}-\frac2{\mathrm e^2}\right)+O(1)\\
&\approx0.097n+O(1)\;.
\end{align}

Comment: can you explain why the probability is $(1-j/n)^{n-1}$

Comment: @emmy: Take $j$ pieces of length $\frac1n$ out of the length $1$ that's available to be distributed, and give them to the $j$ particular pieces that are to be at least of length $\frac1n$. Then you can arbitrarily distribute the remaining $L=1-\frac jn$ over all $n$ pieces, and the volume of the ways of doing this is $L^{n-1}$.